# How to modify or extract multiple file/folder names on Windows/Linux?

Tags: python, linux, windows, bash, batch-processing

[image: A screenshot showing multiple files whose names I want to modify.]

Is it possible to write a program which would extract all the file/folder names in a folder and modify it? For example, I want the file names here to not have `"0n Eagles - "` as their prefix, I want just the names of the songs. Or what if I want to extract all file names and store it in a text document. A general solution, if any, for such problems would be a lot of help.

Comment: What do you mean with "write a program"? Search for batch processing or just batch and you get it done.

Comment: Truth is, i didn't know what other word to use. It must be some sort of code i suppose, so I used the word program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a similar program for my own music collection. This is specific to my situation but should be adaptable for your use case. Comment out the rename call and run it in the root directory of your music collection, make mods until it looks correct and then uncomment the rename call and run again. Might be an idea to backup everything first. This script works on linux and may need some tweaking on windows to cope with the drive name.

A more sophisticated solution would use os.walks() to traverse the whole tree.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
# Splits directories into Artist/Album/tracks
#
# Looks for directories with ' - ' in name
#

import os

for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isdir(f):
        if ' - ' in f:
            print("dir ", f)
            artist = f.split(' - ')[0].strip()
            album = ' - '.join(f.split(' - ')[1:])
            d = os.path.join(artist, album)
            print("dir ", d)
            os.makedirs(d, exist_ok=True)
            for i in os.listdir(f):
                 print(os.path.join(f, i), ' -> ', os.path.join(d, i))
                 os.rename(
                        os.path.join(f, i),
                        os.path.join(d, i),
                )

            print()
```

Comment: awesome! I actually thought of doing this myself, now that I'm quite fluent in python. When I asked this question, I wasn't. I haven't yet tried out your solution, but I'm sure this would work, and even if it doesn't perfectly work, I'll be able to modify it according to my need.